# Fade out AlphaAnimation bug on Android > 5.0

Tags: android, animation

The following code is used to fade out a `View`. It works for Android SDK < 21.

```
AlphaAnimation animOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); //fromAlpha, toAlpha
animOut.setDuration(500);
animOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
{
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
    {
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
view.startAnimation(animOut);
```

Strangely, it doesn't work as expected for Android 5.0 and above. As soon as animation starts, the animated `View` becomes invisible immediately.
How can I fix this?

Edit: this bug occurs if `AlphaAnimation` is started `onAnimationEnd()`  of a `TranslateAnimation`.

Comment: what is the behaviour if you set the duration to 2000?

Comment: same problem, no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html).

Should work on newer APIs (12+) and you don't have to bother with setting the visibility of your `View`.

Something like this (to fade out):

```
view.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(500).start();
```

To fade back in, just animate to your initial alpha value:

```
view.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(500).start();
```

To add an `AnimatorListener`, you can call the `setListener()` method:

```
view.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(500)
            .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

    // ...

}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the AnimationUtils. For example:

```
AlphaAnimation animOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
animOut.setDuration(500);
animOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
{
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
});
view.startAnimation(animOut);
```